# I2C wire.h send 2 variables

Tags: i2c, variables, wire-library

I am trying to send 2 variables with `wire.h`. I tried with  this code:

MASTER RECEIVER:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h> // include la libreria
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include "RTClib.h"

LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x3E, 2, 1, 0, 4, 5, 6, 7, 3, POSITIVE);
RTC_DS1307 RTC; // orologio

static int anno;
static int giorno;
static int mese;
static int ora;
static int secondo;
static int oldSecondo;
static int minuto;
static int oldMinuto;
static int annoGrezzo;
char t[10] = {};
char v[10] = {};

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(); // join i2c bus with address #4
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
  Serial.begin(9600); // start serial for output
  //-----------orologio-----------
  RTC.begin();
  // Check to see if the RTC is keeping time. If it is, load the time from your computer.
  if (! RTC.isrunning()) {
    Serial.println("RTC is NOT running!");
    // This will reflect the time that your sketch was compiled
    RTC.adjust(DateTime(__DATE__, __TIME__));
  }
  //-----------fine orologio-----------
}

void loop() {
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  //   si stampano i dati ricevuti e ricomposti
  //------------------------------------------------------------
  Wire.requestFrom(8, 6);
  int i = 0;
  while (Wire.available()) {
    Serial.println(i);
    t[i] = Wire.read();
    // every character that arrives it put in order in the empty array "t"
    i = i + 1;
  }
  Serial.println(t);
  DateTime now = RTC.now();
  annoGrezzo = now.year();
  anno = (annoGrezzo % 100);
  mese = now.month();
  giorno = now.day();
  ora = now.hour();
  minuto = now.minute();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print(t);
  lcd.setCursor(5,0);
  lcd.print(v);
  lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
  lcd.print(giorno);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print(mese);
  lcd.print(" ");
  lcd.print(anno);
  lcd.print("  ");
  lcd.print(ora);
  lcd.print(":");
  lcd.print(minuto);
  delay (1000);
  lcd.clear();
}
```

SLAVE SENDER

```cpp
#include <Wire.h> // si include la libreria 
//---------------------------------------------------------
char t[10];
char v[10];

void setup() {
  Wire.begin(8);
  // join i2c bus (address optional for master)
  Wire.onRequest(requestEvent);
}

void loop() {
  int mioInt = random(30000);
  int mioInt2 = 1234;
  dtostrf(mioInt, 3, 2, t);
  //convers the float or integer to a string. (floatVar, minStringWidthIncDecimalPoint, numVarsAfterDecimal, empty array); 
  dtostrf(mioInt2, 3, 2, v);
  //------------------------------------------------------
  delay (500);
}

void requestEvent() {
  Wire.write(t);
  Wire.write(v);
}
```

I'm unable to receive `v` in my master receiver. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't have the library to hand, but I think reading requires you to request a certain number of bytes from an I2C address.  You don't appear to be doing that.  Suggest you look more closely at a working I2C library and see how they do it.

Comment: You're requesting 6 bytes when you should be requesting 20, if I understand it correctly, and there is no code in the Master to write to `v`.

Answer (score 1):

I2C is 8-bit data bus, where address can be 7 bit or 10 bit, you can't send more than 8 bit at a time, if you want to send data more than 8 bit you will be sending them like this, for example let you need to send 16 bit data then you send 8 bit LSB first and then 8 bit MSB or vice versa as per your configuration.

Secondly I had noticed you code and noticed many errors, the major one is that **you hadn't followed the rules of I2C protocol** in your code. I am here attached a link for sample program of [arduino i2c slave and master](https://circuitdigest.com/microcontroller-projects/arduino-i2c-tutorial-communication-between-two-arduino). Go through it you will get your answer.